# Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library

Tags: c#, excel

I have built an application with the microsoft interop library Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library

The application just writes prices in an excel sheet, then shows the user the excel sheet

The client keeps getting an error

See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

Exception text:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {50E4D830-B0BD-4DB5-94DB-CC5AB547CDA9} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
   at FXCM.Order2Go.Examples.RatesExampleForm.Login()
   at FXCM.Order2Go.Examples.RatesExampleForm.buttonLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Loaded Assemblies:

```
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4952 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

RatesExample
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///E:/examples/Examples/CS/RatesExample/bin/Release/RatesExample.exe

System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll

System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll

Interop.FXCore
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///E:/examples/Examples/CS/RatesExample/bin/Release/Interop.FXCore.DLL
```

JIT Debugging:

> To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
>   application or computer (machine.config) must have the
>   jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
>   The application must also be compiled with debugging
>   enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>   <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
>   will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
>   rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: Does the client have Excel 2007 installed?

Comment: That asked, the CLSID does not appear to be one of MS's.  Hmm...  any idea what the CLSID relates to?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a problem with loading the COM component with the GUID 50E4D830-B0BD-4DB5-94DB-CC5AB547CDA9, not Excel 12.  Try installing/registering what seems to be "fxcore", some part of Orders2Go?

Comment: Yup, that's not a common Office component.